# MultipleOutputs not writing to files, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm basically trying to write out my own lines of Tab separated values to 3 different output files. Despite defining and sriting different named outputs, all files are still named "part-r-*"

All code has been anonymized and condensed

Driver class looks like this:

```
// Set up job
Job job = new Job(conf, MyDriver.class.getSimpleName());

job.setJarByClass(MyJar.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

// Set mappers and reducers
job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]);

// Set the 3 different outputs
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "out1", TextOutputFormat.class,
         Text.class, Text.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "out2", TextOutputFormat.class,
        Text.class, Text.class);
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "errors", TextOutputFormat.class,
        Text.class, Text.class);

// Run
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

The reducer sets up the MultipleOutput in the setup() method:

```
public void setup(Context context) {
    // Set up multiple output files
    multiOut = new MultipleOutputs<Text,Text>(context);
}
```

And called later from 3 separate methods each pertaining to the different outputs, for example, errors is simplest:

```
private void writeError(String error) {
    System.out.println("Writing: " + error);
    multiOut.write("errors", new Text(error), new Text());
}
```

The issue is that I can see that I have proper output from that System.out.println in my logs, but nothing actually gets written to file. I even call multiOut.close() in the cleanup.

I imagine I'm just missing something in the driver class? Let me know if I need to provide any additional data.

If its worth noting, this is being run on Amazon EMR/S3, but I dont think that's the issue.

Comment: I am not sure if it is helpful. But, can you do `multiOut.write` in `reduce` function itself? Instead of calling a function for it. Sounds stupid, Maybe we can give it a shot. I had tried setting some values using a function that the reducer calls, it didn't work and I got blank values. I can't be sure what the error was since I changed my code after that.

Comment: At a very first glance you must use `LazyOutputFormat`, in order to postpone the creation of output directories till you actually have some data to put on, instead letting the cluster do it on fireup

Comment: try using the `multiOut.write(String namedOutput, K key, V value, String baseOutputPath)` method instead of the one you are currently using. Basically the same, except that you specify the output location when you write. Pass the location to the reducer via `conf.set("location", location)` get it out of the config in the setup, and pass as a locaiton to multiOut.

Comment: @VusP I could but that would make the reduce method pretty crappy looking

Comment: @DavisBroda and Diego, (SO wont let me tag both) I'll try these out today and get back to you guys, thanks!

Comment: @DavisBroda Your method seems to have worked, at least enough to make it usable, see my answer for more detail

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the answer I think I was looking for, but it works. As @DavisBroda suggested, I changed my code to use the `write` method that specifies the base output. For whatever reason, the names I use don't get utilized in the output at all, but at least I can specify different output folders which gives me enough separation that I can work with.

Looks like this, from the example above:

```
private void writeError(String error) {
    System.out.println("Writing: " + error);
    multiOut.write("errors", new Text(error), new Text(), basePath + "/errors/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below statement:

MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "out1", TextOutputFormat.class,
         NullWritable.class, Text.class);